# ArrayList .add replicating the same recordset after rs.next()

Tags: java, arraylist, recordset

I'm a bit new and am working on a project.  I have an ArrayList where I call .add to add elements.  My add is somehow adding the same record to all the elements in the array.  Below are snippets of my code relevant to the problem.  Any ideas why I'm getting the same record twice?

*ArrayList & relevant declarations:*

```
public class dlg_TEntity extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    ArrayList<Struct_TEntity> structRec = new ArrayList<>(); 

    private static class Struct_TEntity {
        String s_id = null;
        String s_desc = null;
        String s_type = null;
        String s_busType = null;
        String s_tin = null;

        private Struct_TEntity() {};
        private Struct_TEntity(String i,String d, String t,String b, String n) {
            set_ID(i);
            set_Desc(d);
            set_Type(t);
            set_BusType(b);
            set_TIN(n);
        };

        private String get_ID() {
            return s_id;
        };   
        private void set_ID(String a) {
            s_id = a;
        };
        private String get_Desc() {
            return s_desc;
        };
        private void set_Desc(String a) {
            s_desc = a;
        };
        private String get_Type() {
            return s_type;
        };
        private void set_Type(String a) {
            s_type = a;
        };
        private String get_BusType() {
            return s_busType;
        };
        private void set_BusType(String a) {
            s_busType = a;
        };
        private String get_TIN() {
            return s_tin;
        };
        private void set_TIN(String a) {
            s_tin = a;
        };

    }

    /*METHOD DECLARATION*/

    private void initTEntityRec() throws Exception {

        Connection cn = null;
        String SQL = null;
        CallableStatement cs = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Struct_TEntity entityRec = new Struct_TEntity();


        *// database call code working fine... relevant snipet code giving problems shown below...*

        rs = cs.executeQuery();   

        structRec.clear();
        while (rs.next() ) {               
          entityRec.set_ID(rs.getString(1) );
          entityRec.set_Desc(rs.getString(2) );
          entityRec.set_Type(rs.getString(3) );
          if (rs.getString(4)==null){ entityRec.set_BusType(""); } else { entityRec.set_BusType(rs.getString(4) ); };
          if (rs.getString(5)==null){ entityRec.set_TIN(""); } else { entityRec.set_TIN(rs.getString(5)); };                                 
          structRec.add(entityRec);


         System.out.println(getCurrDateTimeStamp() + 
             "Populate entityRec with database recordset results  : Record: " + 
                      structRec.lastIndexOf(entityRec) );  
         System.out.println(getCurrDateTimeStamp() + "j index               : " + j );
         System.out.println(getCurrDateTimeStamp() + "entityRec.ID          : " + entityRec.get_ID() );
         System.out.println(getCurrDateTimeStamp() + "entityRec.Desc        : " + entityRec.get_Desc() );
         System.out.println(getCurrDateTimeStamp() + "entityRec.Type        : " + entityRec.get_Type() );
         System.out.println(getCurrDateTimeStamp() + "entityRec.BusType     : " + entityRec.get_BusType() );
         System.out.println(getCurrDateTimeStamp() + "entityRec.TIN         : " + entityRec.get_TIN() );
         System.out.println(getCurrDateTimeStamp() );


    }; // Close while...

    for(j=0; j<structRec.size(); j++){
        System.out.println(getCurrDateTimeStamp() + "structRec index j             :" + j);
        System.out.println(getCurrDateTimeStamp() + "structRec.get(j).get_ID()     :" + structRec.get(j).get_ID() );
        System.out.println(getCurrDateTimeStamp() + "structRec.get(j).get_Desc()   :" + structRec.get(j).get_Desc() );
        System.out.println(getCurrDateTimeStamp() + "structRec.get(j).get_Type()   :" + structRec.get(j).get_Type() );
        System.out.println(getCurrDateTimeStamp() + "structRec.get(j).get_BusType():" + structRec.get(j).get_BusType() );
        System.out.println(getCurrDateTimeStamp() + "structRec.get(j).get_TIN()    :" + structRec.get(j).get_TIN() );        
    };
```

My system output is showing that my ArrayList structRec records do not match my recordsets added.  Am I doing something wrong with my structRec.add(entityRec)' statement?

*SYSTEM OUTPUT*

2013-05-16 03:40:53:042 || Populate entityRec with database recordset results  : Record: 0

2013-05-16 03:40:53:042 || entityRec.ID          : test1

2013-05-16 03:40:53:042 || entityRec.Desc        : test1_desc

2013-05-16 03:40:53:042 || entityRec.Type        : P

2013-05-16 03:40:53:042 || entityRec.BusType     :

2013-05-16 03:40:53:042 || entityRec.TIN         : 123456789

2013-05-16 03:40:53:042 ||

2013-05-16 03:40:53:042 || Populate entityRec with database recordset results  : Record: 1

2013-05-16 03:40:53:042 || entityRec.ID          : test2

2013-05-16 03:40:53:042 || entityRec.Desc        : test2_desc2

2013-05-16 03:40:53:042 || entityRec.Type        : B

2013-05-16 03:40:53:042 || entityRec.BusType     : Not For Profit

2013-05-16 03:40:53:042 || entityRec.TIN         : 987654321

2013-05-16 03:40:53:042 ||

2013-05-16 03:40:53:042 || structRec index j              :0

2013-05-16 03:40:53:042 || structRec.get(j).get_ID()      :test2

2013-05-16 03:40:53:042 || structRec.get(j).get_Desc()    :test2_desc2

2013-05-16 03:40:53:042 || structRec.get(j).get_Type()    :B

2013-05-16 03:40:53:042 || structRec.get(j).get_BusType() :Not For Profit

2013-05-16 03:40:53:042 || structRec.get(j).get_TIN()     :987654321

2013-05-16 03:40:53:042 || structRec index j              :1

2013-05-16 03:40:53:058 || structRec.get(j).get_ID()      :test2

2013-05-16 03:40:53:058 || structRec.get(j).get_Desc()    :test2_desc2

2013-05-16 03:40:53:058 || structRec.get(j).get_Type()    :B

2013-05-16 03:40:53:058 || structRec.get(j).get_BusType() :Not For Profit

2013-05-16 03:40:53:058 || structRec.get(j).get_TIN()     :987654321

Comment: Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.  And **please** review the preview of your post before sending it.  How do you expect anybody to read that mess?

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a new `entityRec` each time you loop in your while, otherwise you will modify the previous instance.

Try :

```
while (rs.next() ) {  
  Struct_TEntity entityRec = new Struct_TEntity(); //here create a new entity         
  entityRec.set_ID(rs.getString(1) );
  entityRec.set_Desc(rs.getString(2) );
  entityRec.set_Type(rs.getString(3) );
  if (rs.getString(4)==null){ entityRec.set_BusType(""); } else { entityRec.set_BusType(rs.getString(4) ); };
  if (rs.getString(5)==null){ entityRec.set_TIN(""); } else { entityRec.set_TIN(rs.getString(5)); };                                 
  structRec.add(entityRec);


 System.out.println(getCurrDateTimeStamp() + 
 "Populate entityRec with database recordset results  : Record: " + 
                      structRec.lastIndexOf(entityRec) );  
 System.out.println(getCurrDateTimeStamp() + "j index               : " + j );
 System.out.println(getCurrDateTimeStamp() + "entityRec.ID          : " + entityRec.get_ID() );
 System.out.println(getCurrDateTimeStamp() + "entityRec.Desc        : " + entityRec.get_Desc() );
 System.out.println(getCurrDateTimeStamp() + "entityRec.Type        : " + entityRec.get_Type() );
 System.out.println(getCurrDateTimeStamp() + "entityRec.BusType     : " + entityRec.get_BusType() );
 System.out.println(getCurrDateTimeStamp() + "entityRec.TIN         : " + entityRec.get_TIN() );
 System.out.println(getCurrDateTimeStamp() );


}; // Close while...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize the entity record each time in the while loop.